# I have an A one, but I don't have a B or (a) C one(s)

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Let's say:

> I have a Facebook account, but I don't have a Twitter or Instagram one.

I'm doubting about:

> I have a Facebook account, but I don't have a Twitter or (an) Instagram one(s).

Is it correct? What's the best way to say it using "to have an account"? (I know I can use "to be on" or "to use").

Answer (score 4):

Try:

> I have an account on Facebook, but not Twitter or Instagram.

or

> I have an account on Facebook, but I don't have one on Twitter or Instagram.

Answer (score 2):

I agree it sounds awkward to say *a such-n-such one* and would go with @WBT's advice, but if you phrase it this way I recommend

> I have a Facebook account, but I don't have a Twitter or Instagram one.

which is similar to

> I have a nerdy son, but not a musical or athletic one.